# Is there a straightforward way to have double-clicking on an object cause another Inkscape document to be opened?

Tags: inkscape, interaction

I'm looking for a way to open another Inkscape document by interacting in some way (like double-clicking) with an object. I'm not referring to linking to HTML documents, just want another (detail) drawing to open when I click on an object in an overview document.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but not with a double click.

You can add a hyperlink to an object by right clicking it, and choosing `Create Link`.  Then in the HREF box in the Object Attributes, type the full path and file name of the other file you wish to link to.

For example: `C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop\test.svg`

To use the link, right click the object, and choose `Follow Link`.  The linked document will open in another Inkscape window.

Comment: Thought of trying that but posted here instead. I always preferred typing lots of prose over one line of linkage. ;) Thanks!